# meteor / handlebars print iterations from self-declared array

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I guess i'm doing something really stupid. I want some data to be available on all templates so declare them as helpers. I then print this array in the HTML with an each loop and want to store the index as value to MongoDB. So later I can print these values with the helpers.

the array:

```
myArray = ["A", "B", "C"];

Template.registerHelper('helper', function(i) { 
    return myArray[i];
});
```

the html:

```
<select>
{{#each myArray}}
    <option value="{{@index}}">{{ helper @index }}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

or

```
<select>
{{#each myArray}}
    <option value="{{@index}}">{{ myArray @index }}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

But not sure if I can use arguments like that in a each loop (shouldn't be different is my guess).

{{ helper 0 }} does work, but of course I want too loop this.

Comment: you cannot access the index of the element from the template. You will need a helper to return that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more simply by defining an array of objects instead of just an array:

**js:**

```
myArray = [
  {i: 0, value: "A"},
  {i: 1, value: "B"},
  {i: 2, value: "C"}
];
```

**html:**

```
<select>
{{#each myArray}}
    <option value="{{i}}">{{value}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```